# Mysql not running after upgrading mysql version

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

Following [this](http://www.expertphp.in/article/how-to-upgrade-mysql-5-5-to-mysql-5-7-on-ubuntu-14-04) link I upgraded my MySQL version from 5.5 to 5.7 on my ubuntu 14.04 droplet. But after upgrading MySQL is unable to start showing this error.

```
mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: It looks like the upgrade messed with your permissions.  You may try doing `sudo su` then running MySQL as a sanity check, just to make sure that it can run.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen still the error

Comment: What does `ls -ld '/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/'`  says ?

Comment: @ThomasG `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May  3 07:54 /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/`

Comment: Have you read this? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.6/+bug/1455773 Looks like it might be an issue with apparmor

Comment: Are you running SELinux by any chance? Could you post the results of ls -lZ /etc/mysql/; ?

Comment: @David
this command gives this output :
`total 16`
`drwxr-xr-x 2 root root ? 4096 May 11 06:50 conf.d`
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root ? 1220 Apr 20 17:55 debian-start`
`-rw------- 1 root root ?  333 May 11 06:50 debian.cnf`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root ? 3505 Feb 19  2014 my.cnf`

Comment: You may find your answer here. Please check this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server/793545#

Answer (score 6):

In my case `AppArmor` was preventing `MySQL` from accessing this directory. I disabled it with:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

I found this solution [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7512#issuecomment-61787845).

Another approach would be to adjust configuration inside `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`.

Comment: Perfect! This solve my issue! Thanks @adrihanu

Answer (score 0):

You try to use chmod to set permissions for the folder

```
chmod 755 /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d
```

mysql.conf.d is a new file can be added

Comment: the permissions are fine as stated in the comments.

Comment: well you helped me out. I already knew the permissions were wrong, I just didn't know what they need to be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the reason mysql don't start or work is because your system memory is probably full, so you may need to run "apt autoremove" and sometimes "apt autoclean", to be sure on what is wrong exactly run "service mysql status"

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps to correct this:

Back up your my.cnf file in /etc/mysql and remove or rename it

```
sudo mv /etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf.bak
Remove the folder /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/ using

sudo rm -r /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Verify you don't have a my.cnf file stashed somewhere else (I did in my home dir!) or in /etc/alternatives/my.cnf use

```
sudo find / -name my.cnf
```

Backup and remove /etc/mysql/debian.cnf files (not sure if needed, but just in case)

```
sudo mv /etc/mysql/debian.cnf /etc/mysql/debian.cnf.bak
sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

In case your syslog shows an error like "mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/'" create a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d /etc/mysql/conf.d
```

Then the service should be able to start with sudo service mysql start.

Answer (score 0):

Some times mysql will not start due to  your system memory is probably full or some dependency issues. so you may need to clean your memory before start mysql.

you can try this to resolve your issue

```
apt-get autoremove
apt-get remove --purge mysql*
apt-get autoclean
deluser mysql
rm -rf /var/log/mysql
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

Anyway these are the correct steps to upgrade mysql

1. Back up your my.cnf file in /etc/mysql and remove or rename it

   ```
   sudo mv /etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf.bak
   ```
2. Remove the folder /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/ using

   ```
   sudo rm -r /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
   ```
3. Verify you don't have a my.cnf file stashed somewhere else (I did in my home dir!) or in /etc/alternatives/my.cnf use

   ```
   sudo find / -name my.cnf
   ```
4. Backup and remove /etc/mysql/debian.cnf files (not sure if needed, but just in case)

   ```
   sudo mv /etc/mysql/debian.cnf /etc/mysql/debian.cnf.bak
   sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
   sudo apt install mysql-server
   ```
5. In case your syslog shows an error like "mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/'" create a symbolic link:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d /etc/mysql/conf.d
   ```

Then the service should be able to start with `sudo service mysql start`

Comment: You should add a BIG note on y our commente. Using purge when uninstalling mysql user will get a message about deleting all databases, so take care about that answer if you don't want to lose all your databases.